# How to scrape all product info from site?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

ideally I'm interested in scraping all product info from the men's section of this website for all pages of products available:

https://www.adidas.de/manner-schuhe-sneakers

When I try using this code to summarize the product names and urls it stops on the first 5 items shown on the page and I don't know why:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.adidas.de/manner-schuhe-sneakers'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'}

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers = headers).content, 'lxml')
driver.quit()

for a in soup.select('div[class^="product-container"] a.gl-product-card__assets-link'):
    label = a.find_next(class_='gl-label')
    print('{:<50} {}'.format(label.text, 'https://www.adidas.com' + a['href']))
```

Which results in the below. Can someone please help me ensure all 48 products on the page are captured? Or better yet, can someone help me figure out how to loop through each product, grab style name, color, price for all available styles, then click next and the same until all product info has been grabbed?:

```
Superstar Schuh                                    https://www.adidas.com/superstar-schuh/FW2293.html
ZX 2K Boost Schuh                                  https://www.adidas.com/zx-2k-boost-schuh/FV9996.html
NMD_R1 V2 Schuh                                    https://www.adidas.com/nmd_r1-v2-schuh/FY6862.html
ZX 2K Boost Schuh                                  https://www.adidas.com/zx-2k-boost-schuh/FV9993.html
NMD_R1 V2 Schuh                                    https://www.adidas.com/nmd_r1-v2-schuh/FV9022.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest going for `Xpaths` and then saving the urls.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

page = 0
url = 'https://www.adidas.de/manner-schuhe-sneakers?start={}'.format(page)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-auto-id="glass-hockeycard-link"]')
all_shoes = [e.get_attribute("href") for e in element]

print("Found {} shoes.".format(len(all_shoes)))
for shoe in all_shoes:
    print('{:<50} {}'.format(shoe.split("/")[-2], shoe))


with open("shoes_page_{}.txt".format(page), "w") as f:
    f.writelines('\n'.join(all_shoes))
```

Output:

```
Found 48 shoes.
superstar-schuh                                    https://www.adidas.de/superstar-schuh/FW2293.html
zx-2k-boost-schuh                                  https://www.adidas.de/zx-2k-boost-schuh/FV9996.html
nmd_r1-v2-schuh                                    https://www.adidas.de/nmd_r1-v2-schuh/FY6862.html
zx-2k-boost-schuh                                  https://www.adidas.de/zx-2k-boost-schuh/FV9993.html
nmd_r1-v2-schuh                                    https://www.adidas.de/nmd_r1-v2-schuh/FV9022.html
ultraboost-schuh                                   https://www.adidas.de/ultraboost-schuh/BB6168.html
superstar-schuh                                    https://www.adidas.de/superstar-schuh/EG4958.html
ozweego-schuh                                      https://www.adidas.de/ozweego-schuh/FV9667.html
nite-jogger-schuh                                  https://www.adidas.de/nite-jogger-schuh/FV1267.html
continental-80-schuh                               https://www.adidas.de/continental-80-schuh/G27706.html
stan-smith-schuh                                   https://www.adidas.de/stan-smith-schuh/M20325.html
gazelle-schuh                                      https://www.adidas.de/gazelle-schuh/BB5478.html
zx-2k-boost-schuh                                  https://www.adidas.de/zx-2k-boost-schuh/FY2001.html
zx-2k-flux-schuh                                   https://www.adidas.de/zx-2k-flux-schuh/FX2044.html
ultraboost-schuh                                   https://www.adidas.de/ultraboost-schuh/F36641.html
nmd_r1-schuh                                       https://www.adidas.de/nmd_r1-schuh/FV8727.html
zx-500-schuh                                       https://www.adidas.de/zx-500-schuh/FW2811.html
zx-2k-boost-schuh                                  https://www.adidas.de/zx-2k-boost-schuh/FX8835.html
zx-700-hd-schuh                                    https://www.adidas.de/zx-700-hd-schuh/FY0995.html
nmd_r1-v2-schuh                                    https://www.adidas.de/nmd_r1-v2-schuh/FY5913.html
3mc-vulc-schuh                                     https://www.adidas.de/3mc-vulc-schuh/B22705.html
zx-2k-boost-schuh                                  https://www.adidas.de/zx-2k-boost-schuh/FV9997.html
ultraboost-20-laufschuh                            https://www.adidas.de/ultraboost-20-laufschuh/FV8329.html
zx-2k-boost-schuh                                  https://www.adidas.de/zx-2k-boost-schuh/FV8453.html
ozweego-schuh                                      https://www.adidas.de/ozweego-schuh/FV9655.html
continental-80-vegan-schuh                         https://www.adidas.de/continental-80-vegan-schuh/FW2336.html
nmd_r1-schuh                                       https://www.adidas.de/nmd_r1-schuh/D96635.html
ultraboost-winter.rdy-laufschuh                    https://www.adidas.de/ultraboost-winter.rdy-laufschuh/EG9801.html
stan-smith-schuh                                   https://www.adidas.de/stan-smith-schuh/FU9609.html
superstar-schuh                                    https://www.adidas.de/superstar-schuh/EG4959.html
carrera-low-pride-schuh                            https://www.adidas.de/carrera-low-pride-schuh/FY9019.html
zx-flux-schuh                                      https://www.adidas.de/zx-flux-schuh/S32279.html
supercourt-schuh                                   https://www.adidas.de/supercourt-schuh/EE6037.html
zx-700-hd-schuh                                    https://www.adidas.de/zx-700-hd-schuh/FY1102.html
terrex-ax3-beta-schuh                              https://www.adidas.de/terrex-ax3-beta-schuh/G26523.html
terrex-swift-r2-mid-gore-tex-wanderschuh           https://www.adidas.de/terrex-swift-r2-mid-gore-tex-wanderschuh/CM7500.html
zx-2k-boost-schuh                                  https://www.adidas.de/zx-2k-boost-schuh/FX8836.html
zx-500-schuh                                       https://www.adidas.de/zx-500-schuh/FW2812.html
zx-2k-flux-schuh                                   https://www.adidas.de/zx-2k-flux-schuh/FV9977.html
swift-run-rf-schuh                                 https://www.adidas.de/swift-run-rf-schuh/FV5358.html
zx-2k-boost-schuh                                  https://www.adidas.de/zx-2k-boost-schuh/FX8834.html
zx-500-schuh                                       https://www.adidas.de/zx-500-schuh/FW4410.html
zx-2k-boost-schuh                                  https://www.adidas.de/zx-2k-boost-schuh/FV9999.html
ultraboost-20-laufschuh                            https://www.adidas.de/ultraboost-20-laufschuh/FV8359.html
sabalo-schuh                                       https://www.adidas.de/sabalo-schuh/FV0689.html
zx-700-hd-schuh                                    https://www.adidas.de/zx-700-hd-schuh/FY0996.html
terrex-skychaser-lt-gtx-schuh                      https://www.adidas.de/terrex-skychaser-lt-gtx-schuh/F36099.html
terrex-free-hiker-cold.rdy-wanderschuh             https://www.adidas.de/terrex-free-hiker-cold.rdy-wanderschuh/FU7217.html
```

Why saving the urls to a file? Well, so you don't have to keep scraping the page and you can use the urls to query the API.

```
import requests

headers = {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "referer": "https://www.adidas.de/en/men-trainers-shoes",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0",
}


with open("shoes_page_0.txt") as f:
    shoes = f.readlines()

print('{:<20} {:<50} {:<10}'.format('Shoe Model', 'Color', 'Price'))
for shoe in shoes:
    id_ = shoe.split("/")[-1].replace(".html", "")
    shoe_data = requests.get(f"https://www.adidas.de/api/search/product/{id_}?sitePath=en", headers=headers).json()
    print('{:<20} {:<50} {:<10}'.format(shoe_data['modelId'], shoe_data['color'], shoe_data['price']))
```

Output:

```
Shoe Model           Color                                              Price     
DVF77                Cloud White / Cloud White / Core Black             97.43     
KYJ02                Cloud White / Solar Red / Blue                     136.42    
KYK47                Core Black / Core Black / Cardboard                136.42    
KYJ02                Core Black / Core Black / Shock Pink               136.42    
KYK47                Cloud White / Core Black / Cloud White             136.42    
DWG43                Cloud White / Cloud White / Cloud White            155.92    
DVF77                Cloud White / Core Black / Cloud White             97.43     
EFK26                Off White / Off White / Signal Pink                116.93    
BTO93                Cloud White / Cloud White / Cloud White            126.68    
DRA67                Cloud White / Scarlet / Collegiate Navy            97.43     
ION05                Core White / Dark Blue / Dark Blue                 92.56     
IAZ12                Collegiate Navy / White / Gold Metallic            92.56     
KYJ02                Linen / Core Black / Orange                        136.42    
KYJ11                Cloud White / Core Black / Blue                    97.43     
DWG43                Core Black / Core Black / Active Red               155.92    
BSV73                Cloud White / Core Black / Cloud White             136.42    
KYX38                Grey Four / Grey Six / Grey Three                  97.43     
and so on...
```

EDIT:

To get *all* shoes (as of now) you can try this and then run the code that fetches info via the API:

```
import os
import shutil
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

for page in range(0, 848, 48):
    url = 'https://www.adidas.de/manner-schuhe-sneakers?start={}'.format(page)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(4)
    element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-auto-id="glass-hockeycard-link"]')
    all_shoes = [e.get_attribute("href") for e in element]

    with open("shoes_page_{}.txt".format(page), "w") as f:
        f.writelines('\n'.join(all_shoes))

    for shoe in all_shoes:
        print('{:<50} {}'.format(shoe.split("/")[-2], shoe))

driver.close()

with open("all_adidas_shoes.txt", "w") as file_to_merge_to:
    for file_to_read_from in [f"shoes_page_{p}.txt" for p in range(0, 848, 48)]:
        with open(file_to_read_from) as file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file, file_to_merge_to)
        os.remove(file_to_read_from)
```

This outputs a single file with urls to all shoes.

Comment: Thanks! I tried running it for the UK site: https://www.adidas.co.uk/men-trainers-shoes

I get this error and I think it may something to do with the headers I set up:

"ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.adidas.uk', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/search/product/FW2293%0A?sitePath=en (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000223B435C250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))"

Comment: Here are the headers I used; do you know what's wrong?:

headers = {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "referer": "https://www.adidas.co.uk/men-trainers-shoes",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36",
}

Comment: Yes, you're overusing the API. :) The error says it `Max retries exceeded with url: /api/search`. Pause for a while before making another request to the API.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not sure. The script for Germany still works but when I run the script on the UK (as mentioned above) or another country (like Israel or Turkey) it doesn't and I get the same message. I wonder if the language set up in headers is the issue? (Thanks a lot for continuing to follow-up by the way :) )